# How to automaticly start process (non system process)

Tags: cron, process

How to automaticly start process if process was killed or finished? For example I've got process name Test, that process was killed because some problem... I need to automaticly start that process with screen command. I need a script for that, but porcess should start with screen command, and cron have to check it every 5 minutes.

Comment: This seems like a design problem. There's often a big difference between "killed' and "finished." Respawning a killed process will often result in it being killed again for the same reasons. There are many ways to start a job on-demand.

Comment: Depending on your response to the above comment, you may want to look at nohup or a similar alternative: https://askubuntu.com/questions/600956/alternatives-to-nohup